# How to create labels for each element?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code. On form load, I want to create multiples labels, the first should be on position (20,0), the second on the (40,0) and till the last label. But the program just shows the first label, I mean label 0, and that's all.
How to fix this?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label[] nmr = new Label[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        nmr[i] = new Label();
        nmr[i].Text = "label " + i;
        nmr[i].Left += 20;
        this.Controls.Add(nmr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `nmr[i].Left += 20;` try `nmr[i].Left += (i + 1) * 20;`

Comment: nope,didnt work.

Comment: Labels created without specifying the size have a default Width of 100 pixel and are positioned at Location(0,0). So incrementing the left side of 20 pixel will leave all the labels one over the other, Also you don't need to add each label in the loop. _this.Controls.AddRange(nmr);_ outside the loop is very small performance boost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  nmr[i].Left = 20 * (i+1);
```

will calculate the distance you want. Yet, you will only see one label because the first label is too long. So you have to adjust its size:

```
  nmr[i].Size = new Size(40, 15);
```

Then you will see that 20 pixels is way too small as a distance; the labels will overlap

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Label[] nmr = new Label[10];
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    nmr[i] = new Label();
                    nmr[i].Text = "label " + i;
                    nmr[i].Location = new Point(0, 25 * i);
                    this.Controls.Add(nmr[i]);
                }
                this.Height = this.Height + (25 * nmr.Count());
            }
```

you also need to resize your form as well,
this code will help you,

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the `Left` value by 20 for each iteration. I also don't see why you are populating an array since you just add the Labels to the `Controls` collection. Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        var label = new Label();
        label.Text = "label " + i;
        label.Left += 20 * i;
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when `i == 10`. As well as leaving `Label[0]` null.

Comment: for sure,logically it has to work,but it doesnt,all what i see is that just first label was created.Try it by your self.

Comment: Ooops :) That's why you should always test your code. I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, replace

```
nmr[i].Left +=20;
```

with

```
nmr[i].Left = 20 * (i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't edit the right property. The right one would be `control.Location` which is a `Point` with the properties x and y.

To add them with 20 for every loop, you actually need to go like `(20 * (i+1))`

Example code that worked:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label[] nmr = new Label[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            nmr[i] = new Label();
            nmr[i].Text = "label " + i;
            nmr[i].Location = new Point(0, (20 * (i+1)));
            this.Controls.Add(nmr[i]);
        }
    }
```

[image: Labels on a Form]

EDIT: Work on that 20 pt. Seems like the labels won't show right. Maybe try 30pt?

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Linq* in order do generate `Label`s:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Label[] nmr = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => new Label() {
       Text = $"label {i}",
       Left = 20 + i * 20, // <- please, notice Left computation
       Parent = this, })
    .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This looks smooth.

Comment: That's not 100% correct. The first label will sit at (0,0), but OP needs it at (20, 0).

Comment: @dymanoid: I see, thank you, I've edited the answer: it should have been `Left = 20 + i * 20`